# Matplotlib Basemap Installation Troubles on OS X Yosemite

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda, matplotlib-basemap

I've been having very serious issues installing `Basemap` from `mpl_toolkits`. Fortunately, it looks like I'm not the only one having these issues... I was wondering if someone could help me here.

I'm currently running OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).

Long story short, I was able to install Basemap via Anaconda after much difficulties. Now whenever I try to import Basemap, I get the following error:

```
 28 from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
 29 from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
 ---> 30 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import pyproj
 31 from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
 32 from matplotlib.image import imread

 ImportError: cannot import name pyproj
```

...which doesn't make sense to me at all. I have `pyproj` installed, and I physically see it in my Anaconda `pkgs` folder. It's called `pyproj-1.9.3-0`. I also have `basemap-1.0.7-np19py27_0` in my `pkgs` folder.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Maybe I stupidly forgot to do something? Sorry if it's a dumb question - I'm an amateur when it comes to these sorts of things.

Comment: are you sure that you're using conda's python and not the system python?

Comment: Seeing it in the `pkgs` folder doesn't necessarily mean it is installed. That folder is just a cache of packages, which may or may not be actually installed into a given conda environment. You want to look at the output of `conda list`.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to install Basemap on Yosemite with Anaconda without any problems, so maybe there's something unusual about your set-up (what issues are you refering to?)

What I did was simply

```
conda install Basemap
```

But here are some things to think about:

- Did you install anything after issuing this command (on my system, conda updated my matplotlib to 1.4.3 as part of this installation. You could try `conda update`, but you might need to do some fixing if you changed anything "by hand".
- Are you using the right virtual environment (the one from which you installed Basemap)?
- import Basemap with `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap` rather than the `import Basemap` that your question implies: see e.g. [this example](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html).
- type `which python` and check that the output is along the lines of

`/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin/python`

or

`/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/<virtual-env>/bin/python`

and that you're not using your Mac's system Python which would be something like

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`